# Display close values in matrix with corresponding coordinates

Tags: matlab, matrix, display

I have a matrix containing values in the 10e-04-range, which are very similar to each other, that is, having only small differences. Two vectors contain their corresponding coordinates.

When I display them with `imagesc()`, the representation is with several vertical stripes due to their similarity. Is there an option in MatLab to display them finer? I tried `imquantize()`, but it only yielded a small horizontal strip.

[image: Sample]

Comment: Can you solve the problem by adjusting the colorbar axis? E.g., if you add a code line `caxis(caxis/4)`, does the situation improve?

Comment: I haven't found anyway to increase the quantization levels. You can try using some of the other colormaps via 'colormap hot' which may help. Without looking at the data the most likely problem is you have positive and negative values in columns which gives you a large range but low separation on the positive and negative side.

Comment: Could you put the image in your question?

Comment: Adjusting the colorbar only changed the colors, but didn't make the figure finer. Please refer to my initial post, I've added a sample picture of how it looks. But the values aren't negative in fact, only very close to each other.

Comment: Please describe what it is that you expected to see. It seems that the image you are displaying has values near 4e-4 and values of 0. You can use `images(...,[3.9e-4,4.1e-4])` to change the range of image values that are mapped to the different colors, mapping 0 and 3.9e-4 to the same color.